# Next focus in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView that I fill with EditText according to what I receive from a transaction. I want to get focus on the EditText on the right or on the first one of the row below if the focused one is the last one of a row.

I did this code to change focus:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            if (position != editTexts.size() - 1) {
                EditText temp = editTexts.get(position+1);
                temp.requestFocus();
            } else {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (imm.isActive()) {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

The problem is that instead of focusing the one directly on the right, it selects the one at the bottom right diagonal from the focused one (see image)

The editText of each cell is saved only once in editTexts ArrayList.

[image]
Does anyone has a clue to guide me?
Thanks!